# deleting directory with large amount of files with rsync -a delete

Tags: rsync

I have a directory called `crmlogs`, how do I use `rsync -a --delete` to delete it?

```
mkdir emptydir
rsync -a --delete ./emptydir ./crmlogs
```

Comment: im using find . -name ".gz" -mtime +3 -exec rm {} \;

Comment: this takes a whole lot of time and doesnt delete much

Comment: This sounds like an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem - why do you insist on using `rsync` when `rm` is the standard tool for the job?

Comment: This is more than an XY problem: <code>\</code>, this is the wrong OS.

Comment: rsync is significantly faster them rm

Answer (score 9):

according to [linuxnote.net's webarchive](https://web.archive.org/web/20130929001850/http://linuxnote.net/jianingy/en/linux/a-fast-way-to-remove-huge-number-of-files.html) is `rsync -aP –delete empty/ ./dir` the fastest way to delete large directories, about three times faster as with `rm -rfv ./dir` or with `find b/ -type f -delete`

since it can take a while, a verbose output with `-P` is convenient or you gaze at an empty prompt line for ever...

and in order to avoid endless scrolling, I redirected the STDOUT to `awk` to display the output on a single line (with a line counter) like this:

```
rsync -aP --delete ./emptyDir/ ./dir/ | awk ' { printf ( "\r #%4d: %-200s", NR, $0 ) } '
```

for skipping the *Permission denied* lines, use sudo:

```
sudo rsync -aP --delete ./emptyDir/ ./dir/ | awk'{printf("\r #%4d: %-200s",NR,$0)}'
```

explanation: `awk` because `printf` alone doesn't catch STDOUT, `\r` to set the cursor at the begin of the output line, `NR` for a line# counter and `%4d` right-pads the line# and `%-200s` for an output string of 200 chars right padded that overwrites the previous line (200 if terminal window has at least this width)

Answer (score 5):

The `--delete` switch deletes files from the destination that do not exist in the source. If you want to delete `crmlogs`, you need to be copying from a source that does not contain that directory. Your example shows you using `rsync` between two directories under the root directory. It is easier to see in this example under `/tmp`:

```
/tmp $ cd tmp
/tmp $ mkdir foo
/tmp $ mkdir bar
/tmp $ mkdir bar/crmlogs

/tmp $ rsync -a --delete foo/ bar/

/tmp $ ls -l bar
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 mint mint  40 Jan 10 23:19 ./
drwxrwxrwt 10 root root 220 Jan 10 23:19 ../
```

Note that `rsync -a --delete foo bar` or `rsync -a --delete ./foo ./bar` just puts a copy of `foo` under `bar`.

Judging by your follow-up comment, I'm not sure whether you really want to delete the `crmlogs` directory at all, or just flush out certain log files that may no longer exist in the source. If so, the `--delete` switch should be useful to you once those files have been removed from the source folder.